# Update recyclerview on Edittext text change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a Edittext and a recyclerview below it in fragment. The recyclerview row item has a textview. I have set the adapter and everything is working fine. I would like to change each item of the recyclerview with text in edittext and somehow it's not working. I tried with  itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on getListForRv() method.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fonts, container, false);

    itemList = new ArrayList<FontItem>();

    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(R.layout.recyclerview_item, itemList);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.font_list);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    getListForRv(10);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            getListForRv(90);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            getListForRv(90);

        }
    });


    return view;
}

private void getListForRv(int k) {
    for (int i = k; i < 1000; i++) {
        itemList.add(new FontItem("Item " + i));
    }
    itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: what is problem?

Comment: i need to update the text in recyclerview on edittext text change @GaneshPokale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this by doing the following, don't know if it's a bad practice but works for me:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fonts, container, false);

        itemList = new ArrayList<FontItem>();

        EditText editText = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(R.layout.recyclerview_item, itemList);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.font_list);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
        getListForRv(10);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
                getListForRv(90);
                itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void getListForRv(int k) {
        if (!itemList.isEmpty())
            itemList.clear();
        for (int i = k; i < 1000; i++) {
            itemList.add(new FontItem("Item " + i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call your `getListForRv()` on edit text `afterTextChanged` methode.

Comment: why are you using edit ext of activity ,if you want to update the recyclerview editext then you should  do this in adapter class where editext data will update by the position

Comment: it's because I have to use the same edittext for two fragments. The edittext is from root activity.

Comment: one edit-text can't work for two fragment, if you want to display same thing in both fragment then it will work

Comment: @rachna it actually does work if you have the Edittext and fragment container in fragment containing activity.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged` will refresh all `itemview`, if you want to synchronize all edittext

I have two  solution:

1. databinding : you can use ObservableField
2. Create a listener and make sure all item keep the listener,when editext was changed, call the listener then all itemview will accept the change